Meaning of "exchange"
Here's an example sentence from a dictionary:

Her exchanges consist of only a few lightweight parries

What does "exchange" mean in this sentence? A point in a discussion?

Does it suggest something else to you? You can get the best answers by editing to explain a bit more about why you're confused. Also, it might help to include the dictionary definition that this example is for. I'm guessing that "parries" is metaphorical here and it's about discussion, but it could be literally about fencing.

OP's query

Here's an example sentence from a dictionary:
Her exchanges consist of only a few lightweight parries.

The meaning which OP's sentence use is related to conversation. (point and counter point).
Ref. Cambridge dictionary.

exchange noun.
(CONVERSATION) [ C ].
a short conversation or argument:
brief exchange
1.There was a brief exchange between the two leaders.
2.We had a friendly exchange of views .


It is actually not clear to me if the dictionary sentence refers to conversation. "Parry" can mean to deflect an actual physical blow from a weapon, or it can be used in reference to a verbal argument of some sort.
"Exchange", be it in a physical fight or a verbal argument or debate, would normally imply that you returned fire, literally or metaphorically. The use of parry here seems to imply that the other person didn't come back at the first person, but rather just deflected their attack, question, or whatever. As I observed elsewhere, not everyone uses language precisely. If they were actually fighting with some sort of melee weapon, then it would be more concise to simply say that "she just parried his attacks".
